# Drop in traffic, but same rank position - Why?

Tags: seo

My traffic dropped recently in the last week. The most recent change was when I moved the entire server too another server. Could that affect my seo some how? What could have possibly happened? My main keywords for my website seem to be in the same rank, but I am getting less traffic from those keyword for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about Google ranking, are you viewing Google's personalized search or Google's Webmaster Tools to confirm that your rank has not changed? Note that, unless you explicitly configure things otherwise, *all* Google searches are personalized: http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2009/12/personalized-search-for-everyone.html

Answer (score 2):

Rank does not relate to traffic. For example, you could be ranked 5th for "snow shoes" all year, but the traffic during the winter would be more than in the summer. That's an extreme example, but the point is that rank does not relate to traffic. If you've got Google's webmaster tools set up you might be able to get a better idea of what the traffic is on the query itself. Feel free to comment if you need more info, cheers!

RE: "The most recent change was when I moved the entire server too another server. Could that affect my seo some how?"  Yes, it does, and would -- though how much is unknown. Since your rank didn't change, it must have not been a major factor.

Answer (score 0):

A simple logic. Just because no body visits your webpage like they used too, does not mean your website is not better to appear in top rank. So... I don't think traffic and rank are related.